# sequare mean error resulting in error -Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have two columns in a dataframe that I'm trying to calculate MSE on. Oddly, it works sometimes and other times gives me this error:

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I've tried to drop nan and manually reviewed, there are no nan's in the two data columns I have.

My code is simply:

```
df['mse'] = mean_squared_error(df['value'], df['predicted'])
```

I think the cause is the values are large numbers but I've tried to wrap the above command in `format( above_command) , '.4f')`

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Both `df[['value', 'predicted']].isnull().sum().sum()` and `df[['value', 'predicted']].abs().eq(np.inf).sum().sum()` return 0?

Comment: Are you sure you dont have nan prediction?

Comment: @ALollz Yes 0 for first.  but 8 for the second command.

Comment: So some of your values are infinity. You'll need to figure out why that is, but once that's fixed it should work.

Comment: @ALollz that's weird..i didn't see it in excel when I manually reviewed. Is there a way to remove them ? I've never dealt with infinity before.